# Count unique value in subquery without group

Tags: mysql

I would like to make a column which counts the occurrences of unique strings from a column within a subquery. However, I do not want to group the results. I need all of my original rows. I saw other posts where the count was selected in the following manner. I get error code 1146 because table_1 does not exist in my database, but is from a subquery. Does anyone know another way to do this?

```
SELECT table_1.columnA
    ,table_1.columnB
    ,table_2.CountB
    ,
FROM (
    SELECT sometable.stuff AS 'columnA'
        ,sometable.morestuff AS 'columnB'
    FROM sometable
    WHERE blah_blah_blah = blah
    ) table_1
    ,(
        SELECT columnB
            ,count(columnB) AS 'CountB'
        FROM table_1
        ) table_2
WHERE table_1.columnB = table_2.columnB
```

Example of desired output:
columnA columnB CountB
1        Red    3
2       Green   2
3       Blue    1
4       Green   2
5       Red     3
6       Red     3

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: question edited to show desired results

Answer (score 0):

The subquery needs to count by columnB and join back to the original table:

```
select a.*, b.c
from table_1 a
join (
  select columnB, count(*) c
  from table_1
  group by columnB) b on a.columnB = b.columnB;
```

Comment: I keep getting an error because I cannot select anything from table_1. It is not an existing table in the database. It was created within the query. That was the original problem.

Comment: Yes, the example I gave uses placeholder table and column names. I applied the concept to my actual query. The column I want to count comes from a table created within a subquery which was given an alias name. I cannot call this alias table name because the "SELECT FROM" function looks for a table in the database. I need to find another method of counting the desired column without using "FROM table_1".